# comparing email id usernames of two columns in excel and printing only username in third column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am in sort of hurry!! I have a database in excel file which consists of email ids and other details in two sheets. Now my task is to compare these two email id (with different domain names) columns of two different sheets and find the common username and print it new sheet.

My excel file looks like this:

```
Sheet 1

Column A

rage@xyz.com
bas@xyz.com
koush@xyz.com
kart@xyz.com
yash@xyz.com
chet@xyz.com
sand@xyz.com

Sheet 2

Column A

kart@abc.com
simar@abc.com
khushi@abc.com
ravin@abc.com
sand@abc.com
bas@abc.com
yash@abc.com
happy@abc.com
```

Now in Sheet 3, in column A it should print the common username I mean like this:

```
Sheet 3

Column A

kart
bas
sand
yash
```

This means these users are holding the email id's in both the domains(@xyz and @abc). As the data is huge nearly 1000 rows it is difficult to visualize through filters. I tried in a way suck like removing the "@xyz.com" and "@abc.com" from two columns and got only username and used vlookup formula. This works fine but the list consists of other domain names. So it will be difficult to manipulate the data. Can anyone suggest any formula or macro for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("@",sheet1!A1)-1)
```

This just trims the `@` and every character it precedes, leaving you with just the username regardless of what domain they have.